# Angular logic chaining in ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logic, ng-class

I'm trying to chain logic in angular's ng-class directive. My code within ng-class looks like this:

```
'class-name': (x && y) || (z && !y)
```

It was working all fine when I only had `(x && y)` but the other expression broke it. This:

```
'class-name': x && y, 'class-name': z && !y
```

also doesn't work. Does anybody know the correct syntax for chaining expressions here? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please post the entire HTML element that uses this? Or at least the whole attribute

Comment: Try wrapping the while expression in brackets: `'class-name': ((x && y) || (z && !y))` - You might also need curly braces: `{ 'class-name': ((x && y) || (z && !y)) }`

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thanks for the answer! The whole element is very long but the relevant part looks like this: `<div ng-class="{'class-name': (x && y) || (z && !y), ...}">...</div>`

Comment: Did wrapping the whole thing in parentheses help? Like this: `'class-name': ((x && y) || (z && !y))`

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot!